# Fermat's Little Theorem & Euler's Theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, totient-function, fermat-numbers

Make a table showing the values of
$a, a^2, a^3, a^4, a^7, (a^3)^7$ modulo 33 for 0 ≤ a ≤ 16, expressing the entries as integers in the
interval [−16, 16]. Explain why two of the columns are the same.

I understand this question involves those two theorems but I don't know where to begin. Do I use Euler's totient function on each of the powers and find what each a is congruent to in mod 33?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Using it for $\;(a^3)^7$ will be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Euler's theorem states $$a^{\varphi(n)}\equiv 1\mod n$$ for $(a,n)=1$. For $n=33$ we hence have $$a^{20}\equiv 1\mod 33$$ for $(a,n)=1$ , which implies $(a^3)^7=a^{21}\equiv a\mod 33$

It remains to show that $a^{21}\equiv a\mod 33$ is true as well for $a$ not coprime to $33$.

If $a$ is divisible by $3$ , but not $11$ , we get $a^{10}\equiv 1\mod 11$ (This time Fermat's little theorem) , implying $a^{21}\equiv a\mod 11$. Because of $a^{21}\equiv a\mod 3$ and the chinese remainder theorem, we get $a^{21}\equiv a\mod 33$

If $a$ is divisible by $11$ , but not $3$, we get $a^2\equiv 1\mod 3$ implying $a^{21}\equiv a\mod 3$. Analogue to the first case, we get $a^{21}\equiv a\mod 33$.

Finally, if $a$ is divisible by both $3$ and $11$ , we get $a\equiv 0\mod 33$ immediately implying $a^{21}\equiv a\mod 33$

Hence, the first and last column must coincide.